# PL/SQL rewrite concatenated query with 'IN' clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

Currently I have in my pl/sql code following statements:

```
-- vList looks like '1,2,3,4'     
vStatement := 'SELECT NAME FROM T_USER WHERE ID IN ( ' || vList || ' ) '; 
Execute Immediate vStatement BULK COLLECT INTO tNames;
```

I think that concatenating of query if bad practice, so I want to make this query without using stings. What is the way to rewrite this ?

P.S. maybe people here can point out why concatenation of queries is bad, because i don't have enough reasons to prove that this style is bad.

Comment: Concatenation of strings is generally 'slow', but unless you're concatenating thousands of strings, I see no issues with your code

Comment: @MattBusche so as I understand thats a common practice in pl/sql code ? Because I have very large queries which produces as concatenation with substitution of table names, conditions, etc...

Comment: Concatanation is prone to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is that you took some steps previously to get vList id's into a delimited string (you don't say how vList was populated ).  Why not keep as one query?

```
begin
...
select name
bulk collect into tNames
from t_user
where id in (select id from some_table where ...);
...
```

Context switching when run many times can be painful, but to me the worst part is that you are blindly accepting parameter input to be a list of numbers, when it could be anything really.  It could (innocently) be '1,2,X', and you'll get a runtime error "invalid number".  Or worse, it could be a SQL injection attack.  Its bad practice in general (dynamic sql does have its place), but definitely NOT how you're using it.

Try something like this:

```
create or replace type t_num_tab as table of number;

create or replace procedure test_proc(i_list in t_num_tab) as
  type t_name_tab is table of varchar2(100);
  l_names t_name_tab;
begin
  -- get names
  select name
  bulk collect into l_names
  from user_table
  where id in (select * from table(i_list));

  -- do something with l_names
  dbms_output.put_line('Name count: ' || l_names.count);

end;
```

You can create an object type if you need something more complicated than a list of numbers.

Comment: actually it's passed as parameter to stored procedure from external app. ;(

Comment: wow.  There are ways of passing a collection of data, this is not it.  How do you even verify that your list contains the proper/expected elements?  If I pass '1,2,A' to you, and you dynamically create a query when ID is a number, you'll get a runtime error "invalid number". Sorry, I won't rant ;-)

Comment: yes, if data will be invalid - stored procedure will return an error. Actually I will be glad to rewrite it as passing collection, but I have no clue 'how'.

Comment: you can also use `MEMBER OF i_list` instead of sub selecting with the `table` function

Comment: @haki yes, I suppose it depends how he wants to access or use i_list, MEMBER OF is another good example.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that concatenation is slow.  It's that dynamic queries in plsql are REALLY slow.    Here's a good writeup of both the how and why to do this:

[Ask Tom: How can I do a variable "in list"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425)

Comment: generally this problem is called "dynamic where clause".